# php sum XML attributes with specific attributes

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<devices>

<device name="Cabina" altid="e2" id="42" category="3"
    subcategory="0" room="3" parent="40" status="1" state="-1" comment=""/>

<device name="contatto finestra cucina" altid="12" id="28" category="4"
    subcategory="3" room="1" parent="1" armed="0" tripped="1"
    lasttrip="1398337234" batterylevel="1" heatsp="19" status="1"/>

<device name="Ingresso" altid="e1" id="15" category="3"
    subcategory="0" room="1" parent="14" status="0" state="-1" comment=""/>

</devices>
```

I want to sum the status of devices which belong to category 3.

In this case the sum = 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use an XPath expression:

Select device nodes: `/devices/device`

If the category attribute is 3: `/devices/device[@category = 3]`

Get the status attributes: `/devices/device[@category = 3]/@status`

Sum them up: `sum(/devices/device[@category = 3]/@status)`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('sum(/devices/device[@category = 3]/@status)'));
```

Output: https://eval.in/182688

```
float(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');
$sum=0;
foreach($xml as $device)
{
 if($device->category==3)
 {
  $sum+=$device->status;
 }
}
echo $sum;
```